# How to iterate to scrape each item no matter the position

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and I'm traying to **scrape** Technical descriptions from products. But i can't find any tutorial for what i'm looking for.

I'm using this web: [Air Conditioner 1](https://www.garbarino.com/producto/aire-acondicionado-split-inverter-sanyo-3300-w-kcin32ha3an-friocalor/31232ba5dc)

For exemple, i need to extract the model of that product:
**Modelo ---> KCIN32HA3AN**
. It's in the **5**th place.
`(//span[@class='gb-tech-spec-module-list-description'])[5]`

But if i go this other product:
[Air Conditioner 2](https://www.garbarino.com/producto/aire-acondicionado-split-alaska-3000-fg-3450-w-friocalor-als35wccr/2d018c0356)

The model is: **Modelo ---> ALS35-WCCR**
And it's in the **6**th position. And i only get this `60 m3` since is the 5th position.

I don't know how to iterate to obtain each model no matter the position.

This is the code i'm using right now

```
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class Hotel(Item):
    titulo = Field()
    precio = Field()
    marca = Field()
    modelo = Field()

class TripAdvisor(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Hoteles'

    custom_settings = {
      'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
      'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20
    }

    start_urls = ['https://www.garbarino.com/productos/aires-acondicionados-split/4278']

    download_delay = 2

    rules = (
        Rule(  
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/?page=\d+'
            ), follow=True),

        Rule( 
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/aire-acondicionado-split'
            ), follow=True, callback='parse_items'),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector (response)
        item = ItemLoader(Hotel(), sel)
        
        item.add_xpath('titulo', '//h1/text()')
        item.add_xpath('precio', '//*[@id="final-price"]/text()')
        item.add_xpath('marca', '(//span[@class="gb-tech-spec-module-list-description"])[1]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').strip()))
        item.add_xpath('modelo', '(//span[@class="gb-tech-spec-module-list-description"])[5]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').strip()))

        yield item.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not good to take elements by the position, the website could change a lot many times, and that forces you to fix your crawler, in some cases, several times.

But you can use some reference that is most associated with the element that you want than the element position.

For example, I accessed the site you linked and opened this [product page](https://www.garbarino.com/producto/aire-acondicionado-split-bgh-2700-w-bsi26wccr-friocalor/94bb0ced55), note that the element with the value of `modelo` should be associated with the element that "presents" the `modelo`:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3 class="gb-tech-spec-module-list-title">Modelo</h3>
        <span class="gb-tech-spec-module-list-description">BSI26WCCR</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="gb-tech-spec-module-list-title">Tipo de Tecnología</h3>
        <span class="gb-tech-spec-module-list-description">Inverter</span>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

So, you can do the following:

```
//*[contains(text(), "Modelo")]/following-sibling::*[contains(@class, "description")]/text()
```

In that way, the `Xpath` does not depends on the position.

- [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) to use `following-sibling`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i need. You nailed it !

Answer (score 0):

For those two, you can use the following css selector:

```
 ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > span
```

Take the first returned match